# How can I add images from a folder to my swift code?

Tags: arrays, swift, animation, uiimage

I am trying to create an animated image background for my swift application. I added a group of 300 JPG images to my assets folder, and am wondering how I can access that folder in my code, iterate through it, and append it to an UIImage array? Or if there is an easier way to do this let me know.

Comment: just use UIImage(named:"imagename.jpg") , this will give u the  image object which u can set on any imageview

Answer (score 0):

You can name the images accordingly to the frame order

**e.g.**

`image0`, `image1`, `image2` ... `imageN`

and then iterate

```
var imagesArray:[UIImage] = []
for i in 0...100 {
    guard let image = UIImage(named: "image\(i).png") else {
        fatalError("Couldn't find image\(i).png")
    }
    imagesArray.append(image)
}
imageView.animationImages = imagesArray
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `animatedImageNamed:duration:`

Let's say you are animating a spinner. Copy all of your frames into the project and name them as follows:

- spinner-1.png
- spinner-2.png
- spinner-3.png
- etc.

Then create the image via:

```
 [UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"spinner-" duration:1.0f];
```

According to [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/animatedImageNamed:duration:),

> This method loads a series of files by appending a series of numbers to the base file name provided in the name parameter. For example, if the name parameter had ‘image’ as its contents, this method would attempt to load images from files with the names ‘image0’, ‘image1’ and so on all the way up to ‘image1024’. All images included in the animated image should share the same size and scale.

and you can use third party library like [FLAnimatedImage](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage) or [uiimage-from-animated-gif](https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif)

Hope this will help :)